# Relate Column 1 to Column 2 in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables

I currently have a script I am writing that will pull a list of servers and organize them by their description. I also added an ID column to these so they are more easily identified. I would like to use Read-Host to have a user type the number from column 1 and output the data from column 2.

```
### OU of servers
$DNAServers = "OU=Location,OU=Servers,DC=Company,DC=internal"

### Server List
$ServerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $DNAServers -Properties Name, Description | Select-Object Name, Description | Sort-Object Description
$Global:i = 0; $ServerList | Select-Object @{ Name = 'ID'; Expression = { $global:i.ToString("00"); $global:i += 1 } }, * -OutVariable $ServerID
$ServerID
```

This outputs a list for the user to see:

```
ID Name            Description                                                     
-- ----            -----------                                                     
00 SHARE1                                                                 
01 SHARE2                                                                 
02 SHARE3                                                                 
03 SHARE4                                                                 
04 SHARE5          A-Town
05 SHARE6          B-Town
```

So the question. How can I allow the user to type 00 in the Read-Host entry so it will output SHARE1 for me as the variable? (I am still pretty new at powershell, so please forgive my ignorance if there is a better way to do this)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to `$ServerID | Out-GridView -PassThru` to allow selection?

Comment: Guess you could do: `($ServerID | ? ID -eq $selection).Name` for the name column based on whatever number you assign to `$selection`; *assuming that's where you assign your `Read-Host` output*.

Comment: Alternatively make a hashtable instead like `$ServerID=@{};$ServerList|%{$ServerID.add(($global:i++).tostring("00"),$_)}` then later you could capture their selection and just `$ServerID[$selection]`